# Erro when using File Transfer Plugin - Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to upload images to my server using

```
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",

"@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.0.0",
```

**component.ts**

```
takePicture() {
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    targetWidth: 500,
    targetHeight: 500,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
  };

  this.camera.getPicture(options)
  .then((imageData) => this._img.uploadImage(imageData))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

**imageProvider.ts**

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from "@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx";

   ...

uploadImage(img) {

  const url = `${this.apiURL}/images/upload`;

  // File for Upload
  var targetPath = img;

  var options: FileUploadOptions = {
    fileKey: 'image',
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: 'multipart/form-data'
  };

  const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('good');
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('bad');
    })
}
```

I get this error in logcat Android Studio:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined"

I have found that the code works well till it reaches this line

```
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
```

Answer (score 8):

You are using the wrong native plugin version, For Ionic 3, you should use version 4.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install --save @ionic-native/file-transfer@4
```

And also, **don't** append **ngx** at the end of the import.

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
```

For your future reference, If you are using Ionic 3, follow Ionic v3 docs instead of latest docs.

**V3 docs**: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file-transfer/

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

you might be missing this line after the imports:

```
constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) { }
```

that's at least what the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/) suggests.

Comment: I already have  private transfer: FileTransfer  but I missing  private file: File... I will try now with both

Comment: I just tried with private file: File and private transfer: FileTransfer and there was a new error so I get back to just private transfer: FileTransfer... I guess the plugin is not working? I would like to downgrade FileTransfer plugin to v4+.. Which command can I use? Thanks